# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:ro.i2c.mirela.board.i2cJNI.U2C_OpenDevice(J)J

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have those java files:

//i2cjni.java

```
public class i2cJNI {
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("i2cbrdg");
    }
    catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        System.err.println("Native code library failed to load. \n" + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

`public final static native long U2C_GetDeviceCount();
  public final static native long U2C_OpenDevice(long jarg1);
  public final static native long U2C_CloseDevice(long jarg1);
...
}`

//i2c.java

```
public class i2c {
public static SWIGTYPE_p_BYTE U2C_GetDeviceCount() {
return new SWIGTYPE_p_BYTE(i2cJNI.U2C_GetDeviceCount(), true);
```

}

//I2CBoard.java

```
public class I2CBoard extends i2c{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SWIGTYPE_p_BYTE nDevice = new SWIGTYPE_p_BYTE();
    i2c.U2C_OpenDevice(nDevice);
    SWIGTYPE_p_BYTE mDevice = i2c.U2C_GetDeviceCount();
    System.out.println("mDevice: " + mDevice);
    }
```

`}`

-I have set the native library path like this:

```
i2c_wrapper/Native library location: ro.i2c.mirela/os/x86_64
 and in the same way to the rest of them: JRE System Library, Plug-in Dependencies, ro.i2c.mirela/os(class folder) and i2c_wrapper
```

-I have added this folder to the project:

```
os/x86_64/i2c_wrapper.dll
os/x86_64/i2cbrdg.dll
os/x86_64/U2CCommon.dll
```

-when I try to call the U2C_GetDeviceCount() function and so on, I get this error. Any ideas?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ro.i2c.mirela.board.i2cJNI.U2C_OpenDevice(J)J
at ro.i2c.mirela.board.i2cJNI.U2C_OpenDevice(Native Method)
at ro.i2c.mirela.board.i2c.U2C_OpenDevice(i2c.java:28)
at ro.i2c.mirela.board.I2CBoard.main(I2CBoard.java:8)
```

Answer (score 0):

that like is a  link error,may be your .c file function name is not right,maybe  you should post your .c
file

Comment: I have used SWIG to wrap i2cbridge.h file and from i2c_wrap.cxx ( http://pastie.org/9119331 ) I have obtained the i2c_wrapper.dll file; P.S.If the link doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: when you use the jni,you should use the use java's tool Javah build a .h file,and then change the .c file's function which you in java file .in this case  you should use Javah and i2cjni.java builde a i2cjni.h

Comment: Sorry, can you be more specific? My sources are written in c++ (a dll file, a lib file and a h file is all I have)  and I want to call that c++ functions in java.To do that I have used SWIG to wrap that c++ functions, so in final , I have java files and a wrapp.dll, but I can't call  the functions written in c++ yet, still have that error. thanks a lot.

Comment: What I have understood from you is to go back from java files in c++ files, but I don't want this.

Comment: Solved, I have put all java files in the default package from eclipse, and now it find my functions from dll loadlibrary.